# Use of 'in which ...' to modify a noun

Tags: prepositions, paraphrasing

Consider the sentence

> Why did the Egyptians not develop sculpture **in** which the body
>   turned and twisted through space like classical Greek statuary?

Could someone please explain the use of "in which" here, and paraphrase this sentence. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

***In which***: *which* after a preposition is

> a determiner used to refer to something previously mentioned when introducing a clause giving further information.
>
> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/which?q=in+which+case#which__6)

In your example sentence, *which* refers to the Egyptians' sculpture, and *in* means the following clause describes an intrinsic characteristic of it.

To remove *in which* unambiguously, the entire sentence needs to be recast to describe the Greek sculptures first and then link the Egyptians to that:

> Classical Greek statuary had bodies which turned and twisted through space. Why did the Egyptians not develop sculpture like that?

There are shorter but more ambiguous methods, like replacing *in which* with *where*:

> Why did the Egyptians not develop sculpture where the body turned and twisted through space like classical Greek statuary?

Here, *the body* is only linked to Egyptian sculpture by context. You might use *that,* perhaps:

> Why did the Egyptians not develop sculpture that turned and twisted the body through space like classical Greek statuary?

Again, *the body* **could** refer to the observer's body, that it's necessary to turn and twist **one's own** body in order to view the Greek sculpture. That's a rather ridiculous concept, so it's understood that the body in question is the depicted body in the sculpture, but using *in which* removes the ambiguity altogether by definitively linking the *body* to the *sculpture*.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of "in which" in the quote you supplied can be replaced by "where" without altering the meaning.

Therefore:

Why did the Egyptians not develop a sculpture where the body turned and twisted through space like classical Greek statuary?